# PhpStorm subversion just stopped working

Tags: php, symfony, svn, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using PHPstorm and subversion just stopped working. I can login to my beanstalk account svn repository with any and all other subversion tools, just not PHPStorm.

Here is a screen shot of what I am getting:

[image]

Why is this happening. I have followed every on screen suggestion and nothing works. Is it possible to fully delete all of my PHPStorm subversion settings and do a clean install. I have tried removing PHPStorm and reinstalling Version 7 and 8 with no luck. I have tried to log into the Subversion settings in PHP storm and removing the Auth cache with no luck. I have tried deleting the ~/.subversion directory on my system with no luck.

I have also created another account at BeanStalk and tried to use a completely different account, no luck.

Why would this happen and is there something else that I can try?

When I add my svn url it just gives me a loading icon but never shows me any files or connects. Sorry I had to black it out, but it is just my url with the "Loading" text.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I got a comment from Beanstalk saying that under the subversion SSL Protocol, change to the TLSv1 protocol and it should work. You may have better luck, since my install is several versions behind and I don't have the option to make the change. Good luck!

Comment: Update: I jumped from version 5 to 8, made the change from SSLv3 to TLSv1 and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error.  SVN integration in PHP Storm 8.0 just stopped working for me out of the blue.  Nothing to do with SSL/TLS settings.  Had been set to TLSv1 for a while.  Tried another box and everything was fine with the repo and network.

I was able to fix it by using the option under the 'File' menu called `Invalidate Caches / Restart`.  It didn't ask me again for subversion credentials like I thought it would.  Makes me think the error message was lying as to the true issue.

Answer (score -2):

Your Beanstalk host dropped SSLv3 support and switched to TLS due to the a vulnerability was discovered for SSLv3 by the name of POODLE (Padding Oracle On Downgraded Legacy Encryption) allowing man-in-the-middle attackers to view encrypted information in plain text.

More technical details on the POODLE vulnerability can be found here: https://www.openssl.org/~bodo/ssl-poodle.pdf